# Hashicorp Consul autoheal health check

Tags: consul

I am having trouble finding an API endpoint in Hashicorp Consul that would work for an autoheal health check.

For example, in Hashicorp Vault there is the `/v1/sys/health` endpoint that gives basic information.

Is there something similar in Consul?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think [/agent/self endpoint](https://www.consul.io/api/agent.html#read-configuration) is what you are looking for.
Just like Vault's `/v1/sys/health` it returns a status of a node but with a different information.
As far as I know `.Config.Member.Status` key in JSON reply shows either 1 or 0 depending on Consul agent's status.